# Calculated Columns in SQL Server external table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, external-tables

I'm currently doing a migration from on-premises to Azure for our application. At the moment the application makes use of cross-database queries and that is no longer supported by Azure SQL server... bummer

But: as a light at the end of the tunnel we introduce: external tables! Whoehoe!

Here's the question: I have no problem at all to port the external databases to external tables, but for one teenie weenie column that makes use of a calculated value.

This is the table in the external database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
...bla bla bla...
[DF_Installaties_MaxGebruikers] DEFAULT ((-1)) NOT NULL,
[Rublengte]                    INT           CONSTRAINT  [DF_Installaties_Rublengte] DEFAULT ((6)) NOT NULL,
[schooldbserver]               AS            ([dbo].[getpubliek_ip_adres]([p_sqlserver])),
[p_SQLserver]                  INT           CONSTRAINT [DF_Installaties_schooldbserverEqualsDezeServer] DEFAULT ((1)) NOT NULL,
[klaskalendersOpnieuwMaken]    INT           CONSTRAINT 

.... bla bla bla ...
);
```

> some code was left out because it was waay to big...

And my first attempt to create the external table is:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ExternalScheme].[ExternalTable]
 ( 

... bla bla bla ...
,   [Rublengte] INT NOT NULL
,   [schooldbserver] AS ([dbo].[getpubliek_ip_adres]([p_sqlserver]))
,   [p_SQLserver] INT NOT NULL
,   [klaskalendersOpnieuwMaken] INT NOT NULL
... bla bla bla ...
WITH  
(  
    DATA_SOURCE = [ExternalDataSource]
);
```

> Again some bla bla bla was left out to get to the point of the question

So the real question here is: How do i do this? The approach as indicated is not being accepted by the Sql Database Project.

With regards and thank you in advance!
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the external table definition acts somewhat like a view as a projection of the remote table.  So you don't need to repeat the computed column's definition in the external table, you just need to include the computed column name and its datatype, which should be the datatype returned by the function in the remote table.  This makes sense as you want the column computation to be done on the remote database, not locally.